# How to fix Unexpected `await` inside a loop error - firebase function -

Tags: javascript

Part of a Google Firebase Cloud Function, where I try to run:

**CODE#1:** [ firebase deploy] cron job to `event-notify-about-upcoming-event.js`.

```
note: /*[L47]*/-> "points to error line Number"
```

```js
const pushToChannelMembers = async (channelDocument, groupId, groupName, isTomorrow = false) => {
  const channelUsers = await usersInChannel(groupId, channelDocument.id);  /*[Line47]*/
  const channelData = channelDocument.data();

  channelDocument.ref.update({
    notified_members: true
  });

  for (const userSnapshot of channelUsers.docs) {
    const uid = userSnapshot.data().uid;
    const userDoc = await getUser(uid);
    const locale = userDoc.data().locale;

    const localizedTimeString = timeStringForDate(channelData.start_date, channelData.timezone_seconds_offset);
    const title = getNotificationTitleForUpcomingEvent(locale, groupName);
    const body = getNotificationBodyForUpcomingEvent(locale, channelData.name, isTomorrow ? null : localizedTimeString);

    await pushToUser(userDoc.id, userDoc.data().token, title, body, "", groupId, channelDocument.id);  /*[Line54]*/
  }
}
:
const pushToEventChannelMembers = async (eventChannelDocs, groupId, groupName, isTomorrow) => {
  for (const channelDocument of eventChannelDocs) {
    const channel = channelDocument.data();

    if (channel.notified_members !== true) {
      await pushToChannelMembers(channelDocument, groupId, groupName, isTomorrow); /*[line110]*/
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

> 47:21  error  Unexpected `await` inside a loop  no-await-in-loop
>
> 54:5   error  Unexpected `await` inside a loop  no-await-in-loop
>
> 110:7   error  Unexpected `await` inside a loop  no-await-in-loop

**CODE#2:** [ firebase deploy] cloud function to `reaction-push.js`.

```js
     for (const key in reactionAfter) {
            // A new reaction was added
            if (!Object.keys(reactionBefore).includes(key)) {
                console.log('New Emoji reaction added to message');

                // get the list of users that joined the channel
                const users = await usersInChannel(context.params.groupId, context.params.channelId); /*[Line22]*/
                // Check if the author is still part of the channel
                if (!users.docs.some((user) => {
                    return authorUid === user.id;
                })) {
                    console.log('Author left the channel');
                    return;
                }

                // Update read flag for author.
                await flagChannelUnread(context.params.groupId, context.params.channelId, author.data().uid); /*[Line32]*/

                const val = reactionAfter[key];
                const emoji = val.emoji;
                const username = val.user_name;
                const token = author.data().token;

                // If the user has a cloud messaging token registered
                if (token !== null) {
                    const title = getNotificationTitleForReaction(username, groupName, channelName);
                    const body = getNotificationBodyForReaction(author.data().locale, emoji);
                    console.log('Sending notification to user ' + author.data().name + ' with text: ' + body);
                    const message = getMessage(
                        token,
                        title,
                        body,
                        { type: "reaction" });
                    await sendPush(message); /*[Line49]*/
                }
            }
        }
```

**Result:**

> 22:27  error  Unexpected `await` inside a loop  no-await-in-loop
>
> 32:13  error  Unexpected `await` inside a loop  no-await-in-loop
>
> 49:17  error  Unexpected `await` inside a loop  no-await-in-loop

Please help by writing the right syntax to fix these errors

Comment: By mistake you cannot use await inside a loop

Comment: can you try this? `for await (const key in reactionAfter)`

Comment: @AksJacoves There's no mistake. It's not a syntax error. Just a misconfigured linter.

Comment: @TheAlpha93 No! `reactionAfter` is not an asynchronous iterator.